# How to modify USERNAME environ variable?

Tags: windows, powershell

My tool uses the environment variable USERNAME for authentication. But on Windows you can type your username in upper and lower case characters.
Windows accept this and put this value into the environment variable. even if your username is only in lower case characters. My app does an exact match on USERNAME and the stored username. So if users change their login name accidentally or intentionally the authentication fails.
Question: How to modify (To_Lower) the env variable USERNAME?

Comment: Fix your application?

Comment: Bill makes a good point, actually. It seems you're somewhat aware about the ToLower method... have you tried it? $env:USERNAME = $env:USERNAME.ToLower. If you'd rather *not* modify the actual environment variable, use a user-defined variable like so: $User = $env:USERNAME.ToLower()

Comment: So, app is not under my control  :-( 
Real problem is, that the environment variable cannot be modified.
 $env:USERNAME = $env:USERNAME.ToLower works but does not alter the environment variable at all (win7/64)...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to this:

```
$a=($env:username).tostring().tolower()
```

In your case you have to again set it back to the same environmental variable.
This is for setting user level environmental variable

```
$a=($env:username).tostring().tolower()
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("username", "$a", "Username")
```

OR, you can use:

```
$a=($env:username).tostring().tolower()
$env:UserName = "$a"
```

Comment: Setting back is the real problem: it seems that it is code which creates the content of the environment variable. I need to change the content for all new processes in this user session. The app which consumes the variable cannot be modified because it is not under my control (license, no code, etc.)

Comment: Once i will be from my system, i will let u know how to set it back in the same variable.m from mobile

Comment: @F.J.S: I have modified the answer. Mentioned how to set it back. Testing in local. Hope it helps.

Comment: Idea was good. Correct code is: [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("username", "$a", "Process")
This changes the content but unfortunately only for this and sub processes. I like to change the value for the complete session. So if I create a new DOS command window the value of %USERNAME% should be in lower case letters also.